# DataGridView current cell jump to last column

Tags: c#, datagridview

When I add this code to my Method my current cell changed and goes to last column in current row

```
decimal value = 0;
var flag = decimal.TryParse(Dgv_ProjectSeason.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString(), out value);
if (flag)
{
    SetPercentOfValue(Convert.ToDecimal(value));
}
```

and method `SetPercentOfValue` is

```
private void SetPercentOfValue(decimal value)
{
    Txt_DepositPrice.Text = Math.Round(((decimal.Parse(Txt_DepositPercent.Text) / 100) * value)).ToString();
    Txt_ContractorInsurancePrice.Text = Math.Round(((decimal.Parse(Txt_ContractorInsurancePercent.Text) / 100) * value)).ToString();
    Txt_EmployerInsurancePrice.Text = Math.Round(((decimal.Parse(Txt_EmployerInsurancePercent.Text) / 100) * value)).ToString();
    Txt_ForceTaxPrice.Text = Math.Round(((decimal.Parse(Txt_ForceTaxPercent.Text) / 100) * value)).ToString();
    Txt_IncreaseValueTaxPrice.Text = Math.Round(((decimal.Parse(Txt_IncreaseValueTaxPercent.Text) / 100) * value)).ToString();
}
```

I have to use this method. How can I fix it?

Comment: So you are getting the last column value? Which event are you using?

Comment: i call on CellClick event of my datagridview

Comment: So are you getting the value from the last column?

Comment: no i get value from cell that clicked and i send e type for getting cell value and never call last cell

Comment: So what is the problem ? I didn't exactly understand

Comment: my grid work correctly when i add above code and call. when i click on cell of grid it jump to last column and change the currentcell

Comment: is there more code in your CellClick event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91001/discussion-between-user3480060-and-abhishek).